# How to get second last entered data - saving in mysql db using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

```
int diffanalysis=Integer.parseInt(history.getDiffanalysisHours()) ;
int AnalysisHours= Integer.parseInt(project.getAnalysisHours());

history.setDiffanalysisHours(String.valueOf(AnalysisHours-diffanalysis));
projectService.saveorupdate(history);
```

I have a problem , I want the second last entered data of history bean. How should I go about it?

I can get previous data but I want the data entered before that.

Comment: Why can't you just store the `lastValue` and the `secondLastValue`?  Whenever you assign the value you move the `lastValue` to the `secondLastValue`, the `value` to the `lastValue` and you get the current `value`.

Comment: Learn standard Java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most obvious way that comes to my mind is to store last and second_last values and update them at every insert you do. the update could easily be done with a procedure or something.

another solution would be to add a column creation_date which will take the value of the insert date and time. then select the first two ordered by creation_date.